# How implement Tests for Depth First Traversal using lists?

Tags: java

I am trying to test my DepthFirstTraversal. Just, how would I test it based on the code that I have written it for.

This is the methods I am using,(The add method is from another class which it is extending from, and traverse method is being implemented from another class):

```
public class DepthFirstTraversal  {
        private List traversal = new ArrayList();
```

This is how I am trying to test it using a List since that is what I declared in the depth first traversal class:

```
@Test
        void willItDepthFirst(){
                DepthFirstTraversal b = new DepthFirstTraversal();
                b.add(1);//add node
                b.add(0);
                b.add(2);
                b.add(3);
                b.add(4);
                b.add(0,1);//connect nodes with edges
                b.add(1,2);
                b.add(2,3);
                b.add(0,4);

                b.traverse();
                List<Integer> c= Arrays.asList(0,1,4,2,3);

                assertEquals(c,b);
        }
```

However this is the error I am getting. :

```
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: 
Expected :[0, 1, 4, 2, 3]
Actual   :graph.DepthFirstTraversal@6536e911
```

Edit: Removed unnecessary methods

Comment: You have to check the return value of `b.traverse();`, not the `DepthFirstTraversal` object itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, you need to check the return value of the `traverse()` method, not the object itself:

```
List<Integer> result = b.traverse();
List<Integer> expected = Arrays.asList(0,1,4,2,3);

assertEquals(expected, result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Other answers have pointed the solution. I just wanted to mention the thought process that led to this situation as I tend to make similar mistake.

You are comparing `b` and `c`. `b` is instance of `DepthFirstTraversal` but not the updated list after doing Depth First Traversal. You might be assuming that `b.traverse()` has updated b and now you can just directly compare but `traverse()` is updating  `private List<T>` within `b` and you need to compare that rather than object `b`.